# background image is not showing when setting size in %

Tags: css, angular, background

I want to set background picture as full page in angular 4 coponent. 
i have "main" component inside my app component. now i want to set full width and height page's background image. 
my main.component.html is he

```css
.bgimg {
    background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/250/ffcc00');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    color: green;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
 <div class="bgimg"></div>
```

Image is not showing. but when i set width and height in pixels then it shows picture. It's not showing image only when i am setting height and width value in %. how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

> and also removing below code in bgimg class it is useless

```
color: green;
font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
font-size: 25px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your parent tags aren't taking the whole page.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
```

Now, if you inspect your code, all of the block tags should take the whole page. If not, surround them with a `size-maxer` class

```
.size-maxer > * {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: are you saying that i should do like this?
<div class="size-maxer">
  <div class="bgimg">
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Not if your div is block-displayed. But you have to set your body and html to 100%

Comment: after setting  html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}  
in main.component.html but still image is not setting as background.
Note:  "main" coponent is inside "app" component and i am using angular 4

Comment: Then you should wrap the `main` component into a `div.size-maxer`

Comment: i deleted tha main component which was inside the "app" component. and now i am setting background image directly on app.component.html and still image is not showing.

Comment: 1 - Is your component taking the whole page ? You see this by inspecting it. 2 - Is you image URL correct ? What happens when you create an image tag to show your image ?

Comment: Just saw it. replace `/assets` with `assets`.

Comment: my app component is not taking whole page. now, how can i set full page background image?

Comment: Then you didn't apply the height and width to all of its parents. You should do that first. And correct you image URL, it's wrong, as I told you.

Comment: image url is rigth. i put another images in my html markup with the same url and it is showing small images  but not showing background image

Comment: With an absolute URL, I highly doubt so ... But if you say so. Set the parents height to 100%, and keep me updated

Answer (score 0):

Your "div"  contains nothing inside. So, it's size is 0px and 0px. The background image is being added to an element which is 0 in size. 
100% of 0 is 0. 
That's why the setting in % is not making any changes.

Try changing **position:relative to position:absolute**

Comment: my main.component.htm is now like this
<div class="bgimg">
    <div class="topleft">
      <p>Logo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
      <h1>COMING SOON</h1>
      <hr>
      <p id="demo" style="font-size:30px"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomleft">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
but still result is same , image is not showing.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you share the whole file with me?